# Adjust the zoom of MapImageLayer, according to what is to be shown

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, zoom, extents

I need to find a way to programmatically adjust the map's zoom when it gets loaded, so that only the sublayer to be shown, is visible in the area displayed in the map.
With FeatureLayer maps, I use

```
layer.queryExtent().then((response) => {
    view.goTo(response.extent).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

This adjusts the view to the region I have selected to show from my definitionExpression value.
Now, with MapImageLayer, I am not able to adjust the zoom automatically.

```
  view.goTo(layer.fullExtent);
```

This does not make any change in the viewable area.
What should I write so that the layer zooms correctly?

Comment: When/where do you call `view.goTo(layer.fullExtent);`?

Comment: @TomazicM, this is called inside `layer.when()`

Comment: Please edit your question and add more relevant code (layers, view).